# Why does my backbone view have no reference to its model (returns undefined) only in IE?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a simple backbone view that is passed a model upon initialization (I am using Coffeescript):

```
questionView = new Quizback.Views.QuestionView( {model: @current_question} )
```

The correspond view looks like this:

```
class Quizback.Views.QuestionView extends Backbone.View
  tagName: 'div'

  initialize: ->
    alert @model.constructor.name

  render: =>
    $(@el).html("<h3>Question #{@model.get('id')}</h3><p>#{@model.get('text')}</p>")
    return @
```

The alert is for debugging, of course. This code runs fine on recent safari and chrome, but IE 8 does't seem to have a reference to the model that the view was initialized with. this.model returns undefined for some reason. Are there special aspects of backbone/js that are unsupported by IE?

Comment: By the way, I should have specified that I am using Internet Explorer 8. I haven't yet tested in other versions.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `fn.name` isn't supported by IE. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name - it's non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another double versus single arrow issue. Try using a double arrow `=>` when defining your `initialize` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm still getting undefined when switching to the double arrow. Both single and double arrows work fine in the other browsers, however.

Comment: Then you have more than one error. If you're using Chrome, put in a "console.log @model" and verify that you get the right model. If that works with a single arrow, good for you, but I do not think that behaviour is defined (it depends on what `this` is when you execute the call, I haven't checked in detail how backbone.js calls intialize so it might actually work either way). But assuming you model is what you expect it to be, the next step then is to figure out whether the constructor supports the name property, which doesn't always seem to be the case based on thejh's response.

Comment: It turns out the problem was further up the stack and ultimately came down to my script tag in the html page that wasn't supported by IE but was supported by the other browsers. Also I had calls to console.log that were causing the entire function blocks that contained them to fail silently because that's how IE rolls when the console isn't activated. What would IE be without a bunch of gotchas?